# Run multiple instances of gtkmm applications under linux

Tags: gtkmm

I'm working on a c++ project that uses gtkmm libraries, each application is assigned an application ID during startup, this is required by Gtk::Application.

because of that I'm not able to run second instance.

How can I achieve the goal to run more instances?

Comment: You mean a second instance of Gtk::Application within the same process?

Comment: no, I mean second process. so that when clicking on executable to make executable run, it does not run if already running(opened).

Comment: So two instances of the same executable?  Have you tried explicitly running it from the command line twice?  I don't think this is a Gtk limitation.

Comment: thanks, I tried that, and the second instance just terminates with no output to the console.

Comment: Run the first instance, and then step through the second instance using a debugger to see what happens.  For instance, an error code might be thrown by the gtkmm framework before it terminates, if that is in fact what is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass the `APPLICATION_NON_UNIQUE` value from [`ApplicationFlags`](https://developer.gnome.org/glibmm/unstable/group__giommEnums.html#ga493d914cf0a466cc9c6b18a44c5d345e) using the `set_flags()` method of your application.